# Alternative to iWeb?

Tags: software-recommendation, iweb

It seems that iWeb is now long dead, so I am looking for alternative WYSIWYG web editors. Free or open-source would be great, but I wouldn't mind thinking about paying a small fee for a mature piece of software either.

Comment: Would Wordpress (maybe together with an OS X application) fit the bill as well? And could you elaborate a bit on what your actual requirements are (use for yourself, for client work, what kind of sites etc.)

Comment: I would say Sandbox is the closet to iWeb in my experience of trying most of them in answers. But is there any reason you don't want to use iWeb anymore? It still works.

Comment: @ShaneHsu Well, it works if you have a copy of it. Which I don't :) And now there seems to be no way of purchasing it, other than getting a two year old version of iLife.

Comment: @patrix it's for personal use, for myself, to build a basic (only a few pages, mostly static) website without having to fiddle with HTML/CSS or other stuff. What I would like to have are some nice looking existing designs/templates on which to start building and customising my site.

Answer (score 2):

iWeb Alternatives

- DreamWeaver -> http://www.adobe.com/in/products/dreamweaver.html
- Flux 4 -> http://www.theescapers.com/
- Web Acapella -> http://www.webacappella.com/
- Sand Vox -> http://www.karelia.com/sandvox/from-iweb-to-sandvox.html

Comment: It would be nice to note that all of these are paid products.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options, depending on your knowledge on html and css.

I recommend one of these:

- [Rapidweaver](http://www.realmacsoftware.com/rapidweaver/overview/). It's not free but it's very polished and you can download a trial.
- [Sandvox](http://www.karelia.com/sandvox/). Also not free. It has a [guide for Transitioning from iWeb](http://www.karelia.com/sandvox/help/z/Transitioning_from_iWeb.html).
- [Kompozer](http://www.kompozer.net/): *"a complete web authoring system that combines web file management and easy-to-use WYSIWYG web page editing."* It's free and open source.

My advice is to download and try them all.

Answer (score 1):

Try EverWeb (http://www.everwebapp.com). it works very similar to iWeb. Similar interface but with a few new features.

Answer (score 0):

BlueGriffon is free, only the manual is not.

http://bluegriffon.org

"BlueGriffon is a new WYSIWYG content editor for the World Wide Web. Powered by Gecko, the rendering engine of Firefox, it's a modern and robust solution to edit Web pages in conformance to the latest Web Standards."

Comment: Bluegriffon now seems to have been abandoned, and hasn't worked properly on macOS since Mojave.

Answer (score 0):

Ancient question, the modern is alternative: [Sparkle](https://sparkleapp.com)

(I'm co-developer on Sparkle)

Also worth noting Sandvox and Flux have since been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

There are sadly very few true WYSIWYG web editors these days. Many are template-driven, using their own document formats until you export the site. Importing existing sites/pages is often impossible or lossy.

Dreamweaver remains the champion, though the subscription price is a barrier for many.

I'm currently using [Pinegrow](https://pinegrow.com), which is also subscription-based, though it has a purchase option. It's the only editor I've found (apart from Dreamweaver) that lets you edit the page both visually and in the code.